# Proper time (hour) using mongoose when adding to database - how?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, time

I had a simple POST method in my api:

```
app.post('/meteo', function(req, res, next) {
  StacjaMeteo.create(req.body, function(err, post) {
    if(err) return next(err);
  });
});
```

Schema looks like this:

```
var StacjaMeteoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    windspeedmph: Number,
    winddir: Number,
    humidity: Number,
    temp: Number,
    pressure: Number,
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

And the problem is that I don't know how to deal with time. Right now I'm running server on my local computer. When I'm posting sth to api the hour is -1 to proper.

For example right now it is 23:10 on the clock and everything I add in database is with "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-12-29T22:10:00.021+0000").
Later of course I'm going to put the code to the server (probably Heroku) - what will happen then?

I can't set the time on posting side in this project.

Comment: So you have 2 choices. send the timezone across the request and let the server manipulate the date in some way or find a library that allows you to create a new date bound to specific timezone. What's the use case for your problem?

Comment: @MuliYulzary I'm sending data from meteo station that I made using Arduino board to rest API which is saving data in MongoDB database. I can't add anything on the Arduino side so it has to be inside Api. Can I somehow change `updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}` in Mongoose Schema to make it save time with my time zone information?

Comment: `default` can be any `function`'s result so I guess you can just hardcode that into the server. Create a function that returns your time with the correct timezone then use `default: myFunction`